# SQL Sum all float nodes in XML

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2012

I have xml like below:

```
<float52>7.667000000000000e+003</float52>
<float59>7.667000000000000e+003</float59>
<float60>3.766700000000000e+004</float60>
<ntext2>Other</ntext2>
<nvarchar3>Idea</nvarchar3>
<nvarchar4>Budget</nvarchar4>
```

I need to sum all the float nodes within this xml. I can extract each float like this:

```
@xml.value('(/float52/node())[1]','float') as FloatValue
```

but how can i sum all these float nodes without hard-coding column names?

Comment: Please tag the actual RDBMS (SqlServer, Oracle, MySql, etc)

Comment: Any chance of changing the XML format to something sensible?

Comment: Is this XML generated from any RDBMS? If so, have you looked at getting the values in a better format? That might be easier.

Comment: no this cant be changed, because they are SharePoint 2013 custom list columns. its stored in SQL. had it be more sensible, i could have solved it by now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sum()`.

```
select @xml.value('sum(*)', 'float');
```

It will calculate the sum of all nodes that can be converted to some kind of numeric.

If you want to be more specific you can include elements that contains the text `float` in the element name.

```
select @xml.value('sum(*[contains(local-name(), "float")])', 'float');
```